# Is there any Web framework or project that provides "Wall" like features

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-frameworks, facebook-wall

I am looking for something that can help me implement a "Wall" like User Interface.

Fundamentally it's an ordered list of modules representing a stream of activities: comments, file uploads, images, video embeds, links and perhaps some more custom modules.

A module can be added to the stream using some sort of multiple purpose form (much like the facebook status form / Google+'s Stream form).

I am planning to implement it in ASP.NET MVC for server side and jQuery for the client side but It would be great to find anything that I can build upon. So far I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi look at this: http://www.stefanprodan.eu/post-to-wall-asp-net-mvc-3-web-app/

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. Any idea if this can be extended easily to support various post types?

Answer (score 1):

This does not use ASP.NET or any MVC, but you can get the concept from here. More like a demo: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/05/facebook-wall-script-with-php-and.html